# How to Fix Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to run my selenium script on a VPS server which as a dedicated RAM of 1GB, but i am always getting error

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/root/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)
```

Here is a snippet of my code:`

```
def automate_test(self):
    # instantiate a chrome options object so you can set the size and headless preference
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/root/chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://google.com")
```

`
Thanks

Comment: You also need the `--no-gpu` option when running headless, IIRC.

Comment: @sytech, i am still having the same issue